# How do I prevent users on using moderation commands on each other?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to prevent my moderators from using the command on each others, I'm not sure how to do it..

Here's what I've done so far!

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!permitted.includes(message.author.id)) return    
    if (!args[0]) return message.reply('you need to mention someone', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });   
    message.guild.roles.fetch('881981815232008274')
            .then(role => {
                    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
                    if(member.includes(permitted)) return message.channel.send("no")
                    member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
                })
            .catch(console.error);
        message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> Done.`)
        }
```

Permitted.json:

```
[
    "550692171531943956",
    "868898022166265907"
  ]
```

Comment: Do you have a specific role for all of them? Are they all saved somewhere?

Comment: Yes, Their IDs are saved in permitted.json

Comment: I think I formulated an answer. You should tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to check it the reversed way.

```js
if (member.includes(permitted)) return message.channel.send("no")
```

The above is close but you have to check if the *array* includes the member id (I think it is ID because of the 1st line of your function)

```js
if (permitted.includes(member.id)) return message.channel.send("no")
```

As for the problem you stated in the comments (role is not given but it still sends `@User Done.`, you need to move that into your `.then` callback.

```js
.then(role => {
                    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
                    if(permitted.includes(member.id)) return message.channel.send("no")
                    member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
                    message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> Done.`)
                })
       
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't give the user the role, but even after returning, It still sends the @user Done. Message..

Comment: Can I see your permitted.json format? 1 or 2 users will be fine as an example

Comment: Oh I see the problem. You should move your `message.channel.send(...) from after your `.then` callback to inside of it. Otherwise, it won’t get affected by `return;`

Comment: Edited my answer to also answer the other problem you had @Axmyo